# Parameters are ignored in python web request for JSON data

Tags: python, json, request, urllib

I try to read JSON-formatted data from the following public URL: http://ws-old.parlament.ch/factions?format=json. Unfortunately, I was not able to convert the response to JSON as I always get the HTML-formatted content back from my request. Somehow the request seems to completely ignore the parameters for JSON formatting passed with the URL:

```
import urllib.request
response = urllib.request.urlopen('http://ws-old.parlament.ch/factions?format=json')
response_text = response.read()
print(response_text) #why is this HTML?
```

Does somebody know how I am able to get the JSON formatted content as displayed in the web browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `"Accept": "text/json"` to request header.

For example using requests package:

```py
r = requests.get(r'http://ws-old.parlament.ch/factions?format=json',
                 headers={'Accept':'text/json'})
print(r.json())
```

Result:

```
[{'id': 3, 'updated': '2022-02-22T14:59:17Z', 'abbreviation': ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much, worked very well! I was not able to find this anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for you but these web services have a misleading implementation. The `format` query parameter is useless. As pointed out by @maciek97x **only** the header `Accept: <format>` will be considered for the formatting.

So your can directly call the endpoint without the `?format=json` but with the header `Accept: text/json`.